# How to make a cell empty if its value is 0

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am using richfaces 3.3. I am using a datatable with many rows. I want to display a blank cell if the column value is 0.How is it possible?

Comment: Just tell me what did you try. ?

Comment: i used rendered="#{(bean.columnName== 0) ? 'false' : 'true'}"

Answer (score 0):

I faced this type issue when i was using ENUM. Means in database it will store integer and on table i will printing description.

Like

```
Enum{ FIRST, SECOND, THIRD }
```

So in Database it will store 0 for FIRST, 1 for Second and so on. On Page it will FIRST, SECOND ...

**Now Solution.**

Put one more field in your entity.

whenever you are getting list from database you will always get that field NULL. Process it like

```
if (intergerValueFromDatabase == 0)
{
      //Set Description field.
      setDesc("First");
}
else if(intergerValueFromDatabase == 0)
{
      setDesc("SECOND"); 
}...
```

No need to do anything on Page.

After procession this send it to the JSF datatable object. And use description in Datatable on JSF Page.

Comment: I have a column whose value is 0 for some records . If the value for that column is 0 i want to make that particular cell empty. is it possible to handle it in JSF itself ?  i tried using rendered tag but it doesnt work

Comment: you can try "CUSTOM CONVERTER". Please refer following links. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_customconvertor_tag.htm and        http://www.pretechsol.com/2013/04/jsf-2-custom-converter-example.html#.Ukpy99JHKi4

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this:

```
value="#{(bean.columnName eq 0) ? '' : bean.columnName}"
```